# How to create individual list items with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to create a new `li` for each variable, but instead I get one `li` with all of the variables together.

```js
var ul = document.getElementById("results");
const li = document.createElement("li");
let vin = "VIN: " + result['vin'];
let country = "Country: " + result["country"];
let manuf = "Manufacturer: " + result["manufacturer"];
let region = "Region: " + result["region"];
let years = "Years: " + result["years"];

li.append(document.createTextNode(vin));
ul.append(li)
li.append(document.createTextNode(country));
ul.append(li)
li.append(document.createTextNode(manuf));
ul.append(li)
li.append(document.createTextNode(region));
ul.append(li)
li.append(document.createTextNode(years));
ul.append(li)
```

This is what I get:

> VIN: 4F2YU09161KM33122Country: United StatesManufacturer: MazdaRegion: North AmericaYears: 2001

I want this:

- VIN: 4F2YU09161KM33122
- Country: United States
- Manufacturer: Mazda
- Region: North America
- Years: 2001

Comment: Please update the snippet demo to show the problem. It looks like there's a missing data object. Also, you can use `const` for all your values. You don't need `let` for any and you shouldn't use `var` in 2023.

Answer (score 2):

You can't append the same element more than once. It doesn't exist after the first. However, you can append a *clone* of it with `cloneNode()`, passing `true` to retain text content. Also, you don't need to create text nodes. Just insert the text.

```js
const result = {
  vin: '999',
  country: 'Anywhereia',
  manuf: 'Some Company',
  region: 'Over There',
  years: '2005-2044'
};
const ul = document.getElementById("results");
const li = document.createElement("li");
const vin = "VIN: " + result['vin'];
const country = "Country: " + result["country"];
const manuf = "Manufacturer: " + result["manufacturer"];
const region = "Region: " + result["region"];
const years = "Years: " + result["years"];

li.textContent = vin;
ul.append(li.cloneNode(true));
li.textContent = country;
ul.append(li.cloneNode(true));
li.textContent = manuf;
ul.append(li.cloneNode(true));
li.textContent = region;
ul.append(li.cloneNode(true));
li.textContent = years;
ul.append(li.cloneNode(true));
```

```html
<ul id="results"></ul>
```